# Does the Visual Studio 2013 IDE no longer complain about ng-xxx added inside elements?

Tags: angularjs

I used to enter in my directives like this:

```
<body data-ng-keypress="callFunction($event)">
```

Without "data-" I would see an error message in the VS2013 IDE.

Now I don't see anything. It appears to accept that without problem. If I miss out the data- will that likely give a problem in any browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data-` is a HTML 5 way, how to support custom *(in a HTML standard not defined)* attributes.

From Angular perspective, we can use or not that prefix. As explained here: [Angular Guide - Creating Custom Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (an extract)

> ...Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:

- Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
- Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.

So the behavior of the 2013 IDE is just not disturbing... if the `data-` is not used